# Why can't I import sklearn into my python project?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, python-import, freecad

I want to use `sklearn.neighbors` but whenever I try importing sklearn or `sklearn.neighbors` I get the same error message.

I am using the following versions:

```
Windows: 10.0.19044
Python: 3.7.3
Scikit-learn: 1.0.2
Numpy: 1.21.6
Scipy: 1.7.3
```

I am trying to import it into FreeCAD 0.20.1 using the integrated python console. I first `sys.path.append()` to the path of the sklearn installation, then try to `import sklearn`.

**Error message in question:**

```
>>> import sklearn
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\RoboDK\Python37\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\__check_build\__init__.py", line 48, in <module>
    from ._check_build import check_build  # noqa
  File "C:\Program Files\FreeCAD 0.20\bin\Lib\site-packages\shiboken2\files.dir\shibokensupport\__feature__.py", line 142, in _import
    return original_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn.__check_build._check_build'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\FreeCAD 0.20\bin\Lib\site-packages\shiboken2\files.dir\shibokensupport\__feature__.py", line 142, in _import
    return original_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\RoboDK\Python37\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\__init__.py", line 81, in <module>
    from . import __check_build  # noqa: F401
  File "C:\Program Files\FreeCAD 0.20\bin\Lib\site-packages\shiboken2\files.dir\shibokensupport\__feature__.py", line 142, in _import
    return original_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\RoboDK\Python37\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\__check_build\__init__.py", line 50, in <module>
    raise_build_error(e)
  File "C:\RoboDK\Python37\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\__check_build\__init__.py", line 31, in raise_build_error
    raise ImportError(
ImportError: No module named 'sklearn.__check_build._check_build'
___________________________________________________________________________
Contents of C:\RoboDK\Python37\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\__check_build:
setup.py                  _check_build.cp37-win_amd64.pyd__init__.py
__pycache__
___________________________________________________________________________
It seems that scikit-learn has not been built correctly.

If you have installed scikit-learn from source, please do not forget
to build the package before using it: run `python setup.py install` or
`make` in the source directory.

If you have used an installer, please check that it is suited for your
Python version, your operating system and your platform.
```

After several attempts of uninstalling, reinstalling and searching for solutions I still get the same error message with and without using administrator access. I also tried older versions of scikit-learn without any luck.

I used  `pip install -U scikit-learn` to install the package.

I also checked the recommended commands:

```
python -m pip show scikit-learn  # to see which version and where scikit-learn is installed
python -m pip freeze  # to see all packages installed in the active virtualenv
python -c "import sklearn; sklearn.show_versions()"
```

And all of them list the installed version of scikit-learn as 1.0.2, so I guess that is working fine.

SOLVED:

FreeCAD used an own installation of Python 3.8, while I installed the package for the system default version 3.7. After I used `py -3.8 -m pip install scikit-learn==1.2.2` it worked fine! Thanks for your help anyway!

Comment: As per the error: "It seems that scikit-learn has not been built correctly."

Comment: Could you `pip uninstall` scikit-learn, then reinstall it with the verbose option? `pip install scikit-learn -v` or similar. Pay attention to what file it either downloads or installs (from cache). There do appear to be [binary wheels for your OS-Python combination](https://pypi.org/project/scikit-learn/1.0.2/#files), but I wonder if one of them is used. If pip is trying to build scikit-learn from source, you'll need a C compiler at least.

Comment: `pip install --force-reinstall scikit-learn -v` may also works; that saves you a uninstall.

Comment: After analyzing the links from this page: "https://pypi.org/simple/scikit-learn/" it skipped a lot of links and then decided to install version 1.0.2 from cache using the file: **scikit_learn-1.0.2-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl**. It ends with a message of success, but when I tried importing it again, it results in the same error message as mentioned above.

Comment: which python IDE?

Comment: How do you get the Python repl where you show the error? What does FreeCAD have to do with anything?

Comment: I get the error when trying to import sklearn in the FreeCAD Python console. I first sys.append to the path where sklearn is installed then I try importing it. I am using freshly installed FreeCAD, so I guess their IDE